# Retrieving information out of a Class module collection in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, excel, class, class-method, class-variables

Currently I'm having an issue/Struggling to understand how to pull the information out of a Class Module. 
How I understand it is if a Class Module was an Excel sheet an instance would be a row and the public property would be the columns I have issued this problem before see link ([Retrieving information from a Class module VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34207812/retrieving-information-from-a-class-module-vb-net)) here is where i am with the code

In side my Class Module

```
Public Class tDCVillains 
    Public Property Gothem As Integer
    Public Property metropolis as Integer
End Class
```

Inserting the Information into the Class Module

```
Sub GrabAccessInfo()
  Dim DCVillains As New tDCVillains
  Dim VillainsCollection As New Collection
  DCVillains.Gothem = rst("Gothem").Value
  DCVillains.metropolis = rst("metropolis").Value
  VillainsCollection.Add(DCVillains)
  rst.MoveNext()
End Sub
```

Retrieving information out of the Class Module

```
Sub RackSlotAccess(DCVillains As tDCVillains)
    For Each tDCVillains As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In tDCVillains ' its not liking tDCVillains  
        Dim ObjGothem = DCVillains.Gothem
        Dim Objmetropolis = DCVillains.metropolis
        If ObjGothem >= 1 Then 
              InsertGothemVillains(ObjGothem, 32, "I", Slot, Rack)
        End If
        If Objmetropolis >= 1 Then 
              InsertmetropolisVillains(Objmetropolis, 16, "I", Slot, Rack)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

its the for each statement the code doesn't like but i cant figure out why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if you want to loop the properties of the type `tDCVillains`. You can use  [`Type.GetProperties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Sub RackSlotAccess(DCVillains As tDCVillains)
    Dim type = GetType(tDCVillains)
    For Each tDCVillains As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In type.GetProperties()  
        Dim ObjGothem = DCVillains.Gothem
        Dim Objmetropolis = DCVillains.metropolis
        If ObjGothem >= 1 Then
            InsertGothemVillains(ObjGothem, 32, "I", Slot, Rack)
        End If
        If Objmetropolis >= 1 Then
            InsertmetropolisVillains(Objmetropolis, 16, "I", Slot, Rack)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: the VB.Net Script doesn't like GetProperties

Comment: @AlexGale: you have used `GetType(tDCVillains).Getproperties()`? Is it VB.NET or VB-Script?

Comment: the VB.Net Script doesn't like GetProperties() 
the Help in VB.Net Says: `Function Type.Getproperty(Name as string, blindingAttr as reflection.BindingFlags, binder as reflection.Binder, ReturnTyoe as type(), modifier As Reflection.ParameterModifier()) as Reflection.PropertyInfo(+6 overloads)

Comment: No I have wrote it as you put it above

Comment: @AlexGale: if i test the code i don't get any compiler errors apart from the missing `InsertmetropolisVillains` method. What version of .NET are you using? [`Type.Getproperties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb(v=vs.110).aspx) works since .NET 2.0

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Express 2015 version 4.6, the compiling error i get says;  Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error BC30516 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'GetProperty' accepts this number of arguments. Telemetry Import L:\SI\Exportall\Telemetry Import\Telemetry Import\Telemetry Import\ExportIO.vb 112

Comment: @AlexGale: i haven't used `GetProperty` but `GetProperties`. You want to loop all properties, you don't need a single property, do you?